# How can i post value of input in html to a function in javascript for Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-ajax

I have a HTML page that has radio button ,combo box, textfield and an button for search.
I want when i type text in textfield and then i select one vale of radio button and combo box , when i click on search button ,result from database will show  base on this values:value of radio button +value of combo box +value of textfield .I want these values be as parameters for ShowResult(str) function that it do Ajax.My code is:

```
function ShowResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("Div1").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" onclick="ShowResult(str)" /><br />
 <select name="combox" >
 <option value="Des">Descending</option>
 <option value="Ase">Ascending</option>
 </select><br />
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Added_date"/> Added_date<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Price"/>      Price<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Name"/>       Name<br/>
   </form>

   <div id="Div1" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but i don't know how these values has been passed to ShowResult(str) ???
Please help me.

Comment: Where is this `ShowResult()`?

Comment: Show us your javascript.

Comment: Don't try to pass the values as parameters for `ShowResult()`. The function should get the values itself and then do the AJAX call. This is pretty easy to do if you're will using to use jQuery.

Comment: I don't know jQuery.I want only use javascript,asp.net and ajax.I put javaScript in my code;)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this may help u it.
<script>
    function ShowResult() {
      var txtsearch=$("#Text1").val();
      var value =combox.options[combox.selectedIndex].value
      var radios = document.getElementsByName("group1");

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            alert(radios[i].value);
            var radioval=radios[i].value;
            break;
           }
         }
     var param="SearchText:"txtsearch,"Combo boxvalue:"value ,"radiobuttonvalue:"radios ;
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: your servive url
            data: param,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function (ErrorResponse) {



            }
        });
    }
</script>
<form>
<input id="Text1" type="text" />     
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Search" onclick="ShowResult" />
<select name="combox" >
 <option value="Des">Descending</option>
 <option value="Ase">Ascending</option>
 </select><br />

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Added_date"/> Added_date<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Price"/>      Price<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Name"/>       Name<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: what are contentType: 'application/json',dataType: 'json',? what is 'json'? javascript code doesn't need to xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {?
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }